# What is the operating mechanism of robotframework? Why not execute the code?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am running a robot script, when it runs to `Click Button    btn_submitFile`, the robotframework no longer executes the next statement.
Robotframework keeps running, neither throwing an exception nor terminating.

I do the following:

```
    Execute Javascript    openSetGmjj()
    Select Frame    id=selectFareScope
    SeleniumLibrary.Input Text    search    As109
    Execute Javascript    getSortedTrade()
    Click Element    levelCk3_6052
    Click Button    btn_submitFile    
    Unselect Frame
    Execute Javascript    next('s2')
```

`openSetGmjj()` will insert an iframe whose ID is `selectFareScope` into the HTML document.Clicking the button `btn_submitFile` will remove this iframe.

Log is as follows:

```
INFO : Clicking button 'btn_submitFile'.
DEBUG : GET http://localhost:22400/session/18730e1d-1883-4c90-90fe-d3ebb25ca98a/url {}
DEBUG : Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:22400
DEBUG : http://localhost:22400 "GET /session/18730e1d-1883-4c90-90fe-d3ebb25ca98a/url HTTP/1.1" 200 154
DEBUG : Finished Request
DEBUG : POST http://localhost:22400/session/18730e1d-1883-4c90-90fe-d3ebb25ca98a/elements {"using": "xpath", "value": "//input[(@id='btn_submitFile' or @name='btn_submitFile' or @value='btn_submitFile' or @src='btn_submitFile' or @src='http://localhost:2600/businessRegistration/gtgsh/btn_submitFile')]"}
DEBUG : Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:22400
DEBUG : http://localhost:22400 "POST /session/18730e1d-1883-4c90-90fe-d3ebb25ca98a/elements HTTP/1.1" 200 111
DEBUG : Finished Request
DEBUG : POST http://localhost:22400/session/18730e1d-1883-4c90-90fe-d3ebb25ca98a/element/32f7546b-3d6e-49b3-ae0a-3c09293195d4/click {"id": "32f7546b-3d6e-49b3-ae0a-3c09293195d4"}
DEBUG : Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:22400
```

The program is waiting here. And when I actually click on the button on the page, the program will continue to execute.
Why does this happen? How can I avoid it?